# Waiting until a variable exists with typeof causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

I need a function that waits until a variable comes into existence.

```
function wait(variable, callback) {
    if (typeof variable !== "undefined")
        callback();
    else
        setTimeout(function () {
            wait(variable, callback);
        }, 0)
}
```

Calling this function with the example code below causes an infinite loop.

```
var a;
wait(a, function(){console.log('success')});
setTimeout(function(){a=1}, 1000)
```

Why?

Comment: Variables are passed by value, not by reference, so you're just passing the current, undefined value in your `setTimeout`.

Comment: You're passing the value of `a`, which will always be `undefined`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JavaScript is [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language), so when you pass `a` to `wait`, you just pass the value `undefined`.

You can try passing a function for the wait condition instead:

```js
var a;
console.log('started');
wait(function(){return a}, function(){console.log('success')});
setTimeout(function(){a=1}, 1000)

function wait(condition, callback) {
    if (typeof condition() !== "undefined") {
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            wait(condition, callback);
        }, 0)
    }
}
```

You could also extend this method to wait for more than just the variable existing, but for when it has a certain value or something.

If you use NPM and promises, there's a library that does this already: [wait-until-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-until-promise). There may be others that use classical callbacks as well.

Comment: I'd suggest putting the entire `typeof` check inside the condition

Comment: I suggest that in the sentence after the snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck by 2 days trying to make promises work but I could make it work with your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var a ;
function wait(callback) {
if (typeof a !== "undefined") callback();
else setTimeout(function () {
        wait(callback);
    }, 0)
}
wait(function(){console.log('success')});
setTimeout(function(){a=1},1000)
```